# jquery trigger custom global event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I would like to do something like this

```
$("#A").on("click", function(){
    $.event.trigger({type:"custom"});
});
$("#B").on("custom", function(e){
    $("#B").removeClass("hidden");
});
$("#C").on("custom", function(e){
    alert("something");
}
```

Where I trigger a custom event using JavaScript. I would then like to be able to use the `.on` function on different elements throughout the page. Clicking the "#A" would then trigger the event for all registered elements.

I noticed that the trigger function is called on an element instead of globally, which is not what I want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLKn3/2/)

Comment: [Amplify](http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/) is an excellent, tiny library that will give you a global pub/sub system.

Comment: Thanks Amplify was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Just change $.event.trigger({type:"custom"}); to $('*').trigger('custom');

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you change your code to this:

```
$("#A").on("click", function(){
    $(document).trigger("custom");
});
$(document).on("custom", function(e){
    $("#B").removeClass("hidden");
});
$(document).on("custom", function(e){
    alert("something");
});
```

It should work. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qLKn3/3/)